FATAL EXCEPTION:DefaultDispatcher-worker-5 Can't create handler inside thread Threadthat has not called Looper.prepare()
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-5
Process: com.shoptheworldonline.android, PID: 5088
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-5,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:227)
at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:129)
at android.app.Activity.(Activity.java:925)
at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.(ComponentActivity.java:51)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.(ComponentActivity.java:282)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.(FragmentActivity.java:108)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.(AppCompatActivity.java:96)
at com.example.shoptheworld.android.utils.ErrorService.(ErrorService.kt:23)
at com.example.shoptheworld.android.PaymentActivity.callPaymentMethod(PaymentActivity.kt:413)
at com.example.shoptheworld.android.PaymentActivity.access$callPaymentMethod(PaymentActivity.kt:60)
at com.example.shoptheworld.android.PaymentActivity$onCreate$4$1.invokeSuspend(PaymentActivity.kt:239)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:103)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@898620e, Dispatchers.IO]
while clicking the payment option in the mobile APP and i click to continue it displays the above error, How to Handle this?

UI handling should be on UI thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare?rq=2

may be you're attempting to perform UI operations from a background thread, which is not allowed in Android.
try run on main thread
like this in Kotlin
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch { // Your UI code here } 
